# Difference between "nenhum" and "nem um" (Diferença entre "nenhum" e "nem um")

Tags: uso-de-palavras

What's the difference between them? When to use each one?

What changes in these sentences:

> Nenhuma pessoa foi na festa.

and

> Nem uma pessoa foi na festa.

?

---

Qual a diferença entre os dois? Quando usar?

O que muda nas frases:

> Nenhuma pessoa foi na festa.

e

> Nem uma pessoa foi na festa.

?

Comment: O segundo exemplo me soa bem estranho.

Comment: Pode soar estranho, mas está correto.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Nenhum* qualifica ou substitui um substantivo:

- *Nenhum animal foi maltratado durante as filmagens.*
- *Nenhum dos ocupantes saiu ferido do acidente.*
- *Procurei um mercado aberto, mas não achei nenhum.*

Ele pode vir antes ou depois do substantivo que qualifica:

- *nenhum animal* = *animal nenhum* = *animal algum*

Já o *nem um* sempre vem antes do substantivo, e costuma forçar um sentido um pouco diferente:

- *nenhum louco faria isso*
  (nenhuma pessoa louca, mas talvez uma pessoa sã fizesse)
- *nem um louco faria isso*
  (ninguém faria, nem mesmo um louco)

O *nenhum* dá mais foco para o substantivo que ele acompanha. O *nem um* desloca o foco mais para o *nem* do que para a locução *um [algo]*:

```
(nenhum louco) faria isso
nem (um louco) faria isso
```

Comment: Poderia explicar o motivo de a paráfrase de "Não tinha nem um inseto ali" ser "Não havia **nada nem ninguém** ali"? Por que "nada nem ninguém"? Na frase não se refere apenas aos insetos?

Comment: Vai depender do contexto, dependendo do tom de voz ou do texto em que isso está inserido pode dar outro sentido, que foi o que eu tentei mostrar.

Comment: Se não ficou claro, pense neste outro exemplo: *nenhum louco faria isso* (nenhuma pessoa louca, mas talvez uma pessoa sã fizesse) vs. *nem um louco faria isso* (ninguém faria, nem mesmo um louco).

Comment: Aaah, sim, agora entendi. Desculpe o incômodo. : )

Comment: Troquei o exemplo na resposta, esse meu último é mais claro mesmo :)

Comment: Muito boa... nunca prestei atenção nisso

Comment: Apaguei minha resposta visto que o @bfavaretto respondeu brilhantemente o questionamento do OP